# Django queryset contains a reference to an outer query

Tags: django

I have two related models in Django.

```
class System(models.Model):
    system_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class DangerRating(models.Model):
    rating_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    system = models.ForeignKey('System', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='danger_rating_units')
    value = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'm trying to use annotation to calculate the sum of values of the *newest* ten objects of DangerRating class for each system. I need this as an additional field 'danger_rating' to be used in a serializer.

If I needed the sum of all values for each system it would be super easy, but since I only need ten newest ones I have to make a subquery, and I'm struggling to make it work.

```
        systems = System.objects.annotate(
            danger_rating=Subquery(DangerRating.objects.filter(system__system_id=OuterRef('pk')).order_by(
                '-timestamp')[:10].aggregate(rate_sum=Sum('value'))['rate_sum'])
        )
```

With this code I am getting an error:

> ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and
> may only be used in a subquery.

What does this even mean?